# patchValue to set value and disable the field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm pushing a FormArray with some values, and i need to dynamically set disabled property in certain fields after i've loaded a list.
My question is: IS there a way to set the value and set the disabled property using only patchValue?

I've tried something like  this.rowArray.controls[index].patchvalue({format: "NUMBER", disabled:true}) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  this.rowList.forEach((el, index) => {
              this.rowArray.push(
                this.fb.group(
                  {
                    name: new FormControl(el.name, [
                      Validators.required,
                      Validators.maxLength(30),
                      Validators.pattern(this.BAN_SPECIAL_BUT_UNDERSCORE)
                    ]),
                    source: new FormControl(el.source, Validators.required)
.....
```

and after that

```
    if (this.rowArray.controls[index].get("source").value === "CSV") {
                this.rowArray.controls[index].patchValue({
                  format: "NUMBER",
                  disabled: true
                });
              }
```

rowList is my matrix that comes from backEnd.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can dynamically set your FormControl to be disabled by using the `disable()` method.

As stated on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue), `patchValue()` will not work, as it is only used for setting the values (and not the state) of your FormControl.

> Patches the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object with control
>   names as keys, and does its best to match the values to the correct
>   controls in the group.

```
this.rowArray.controls[index].get('source').disable();
```

Comment: Worked for me, but the value field wasn't populated, so I had do re-enable it jsut before my POST method, and then re-launch my enable/disable method.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples can be found in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue).

Use the same way to disable controls when initializing them.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
     format: new FormControl(),
     otherControl: new FormControl({ value: "CustomValue", disabled: true }) //"otherControl" initializes disabled
})
```

```
this.form.patchValue({
   format: { value: "CustomValue", disabled: true },  //Disable control by pathValue      
})
```

Same applies when resetting.

```
form.reset({
  format: {value: 'customValue', disabled: true}, //Disable control by reset
  otherControl: 'last'
});
```